# Kafka Streams: Kafka Streams application stuck rebalancing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

After all Kafka brokers restart to upgrade offset.retention.minutes setting (to increase it to 60 days), the Kafka Streams application consuming there were stuck, and the consumer group shows rebalancing:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server ${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS} --describe --group stream-processor | sort 

Warning: Consumer group 'stream-processor' is rebalancing.

TOPIC                  PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
customers              0          84263           84288           25              -               -               -
customers              1          71731           85068           13337           -               -               -
customers              10         71841           84801           12960           -               -               -
customers              11         84273           84336           63              -               -               -
customers              12         84189           84297           108             -               -               -
customers              13         83969           84051           82              -               -               -
customers              14         84693           84767           74              -               -               -
customers              15         84472           84556           84              -               -               -
customers              2          84175           84239           64              -               -               -
customers              3          71719           71719           0               -               -               -
customers              4          71446           84499           13053           -               -               -
customers              5          84291           84361           70              -               -               -
customers              6          71700           71700           0               -               -               -
customers              7          72003           85235           13232           -               -               -
customers              8          84521           84587           66              -               -               -
customers              9          71513           71513           0               -               -               -
customers-intermediate 0          102774          102792          18              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 1          102931          103028          97              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 10         102883          102965          82              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 11         102723          102861          138             -               -               -
customers-intermediate 12         102797          102931          134             -               -               -
customers-intermediate 13         102339          102460          121             -               -               -
customers-intermediate 14         103227          103321          94              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 15         103231          103366          135             -               -               -
customers-intermediate 2          102637          102723          86              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 3          84620           103297          18677           -               -               -
customers-intermediate 4          102596          102687          91              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 5          102980          103071          91              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 6          84385           103058          18673           -               -               -
customers-intermediate 7          103559          103652          93              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 8          103243          103312          69              -               -               -
customers-intermediate 9          84211           102772          18561           -               -               -
events                 15         11958555        15231834        3273279         -               -               -
events                 3          1393386         16534651        15141265        -               -               -
events                 4          1149540         15390069        14240529        -               -               -
visitors               15         2774874         2778873         3999            -               -               -
visitors               3          603242          603324          82              -               -               -
visitors               4          565266          565834          568
```

The streaming application was restarted too, and afterwards I could see some processing logs for about 20 hours and then stopped processing.

It's been like this for two days. But it is also worth mentioning that all topics you see above have 16 partitions, but some show three of them (visitors, events). However I can describe the topics and they have their partitions well distributed as usual and I can find nothing strange there.

What could have happened? 
After application restart, I can see all partitions again, and the applications consuming from topic partitions. However many (most) partitions had lost their offsets. Since I changed the `offset.retention.minutes` setting, this should not have happened.

```
events                 0          -               14538261        -               stream-processor-01f7ecea-4e50-4505-a8e7-8c536058b7bc-StreamThread-1-consumer-a8a6e989-d6c1-472f-aec5-3ae637d87b9e /ip2  stream-processor-01f7ecea-4e50-4505-a8e7-8c536058b7bc-StreamThread-1-consumer
events                 1          49070           13276094        13227024        stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer-69da45eb-b0b2-4ad8-a831-8aecf6849892 /ip1  stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer
events                 10         -               15593746        -               stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer-69da45eb-b0b2-4ad8-a831-8aecf6849892 /ip1  stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer
events                 11         -               15525487        -               stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer-69da45eb-b0b2-4ad8-a831-8aecf6849892 /ip1  stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer
events                 12         -               21863908        -               stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer-69da45eb-b0b2-4ad8-a831-8aecf6849892 /ip1  stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer
events                 13         -               15810925        -               stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer-69da45eb-b0b2-4ad8-a831-8aecf6849892 /ip1  stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer
events                 14         -               13509742        -               stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer-69da45eb-b0b2-4ad8-a831-8aecf6849892 /ip1  stream-processor-44fefb47-23b1-4597-8a6b-d7f1c364c316-StreamThread-1-consumer
events                 15         11958555        15231834        3273279         stream-processor-01f7ecea-4e50-4505-a8e7-8c536058b7bc-StreamThread-1-consumer-a8a6e989-d6c1-472f-aec5-3ae637d87b9e /ip2  stream-processor-01f7ecea-4e50-4505-a8e7-8c536058b7bc-StreamThread-1-consumer
...
```

Kafka 1.1.0, Kafka Streams 1.0

**UPDATE** Still happening on 2.1.1.